# How to joint unlabeled colums and values with labels in separate file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe which is basically a table that looks like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |

Then, I have a file, which is is a single column table that contains columns and values labels:

A

Variable A

1

Red

2

Blue

3

Green

B

Variable B

1

Dog

2

Cat

3

Mouse

C

Variable C

1

Car

2

House

3

Tree

D

Variable D

1

Football

2

Basketball

3

Hockey

My goal is to connect these two files into one dataframe, that will looks like this:

| A. Variable A | B. Variable B | C. Variable C | D. Variable D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Dog | House | Hockey |
| Blue | Cat | Car | Basketball |
| Green | Dog | Tree | Hockey |

Do you have any ideat how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: do you really have blank lines in the file? Can you wrap the content in triple backticks for correct formatting?

Comment: rather easy to do with `.map`. But you need to share precisely what that 2nd file looks like. It'll be dependant on that.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to convert that second file into a dictionary and then map those new values. It's tough to do it with what you provided (as I'd need to see exactly what that 2nd file looks like), but this is the general idea:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'A':[1,2,3],
        'B':[1,2,1],
        'C':[2,1,3],
        'D':[3,2,3]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)




data2 = ['A','Variable A',1,'Red',2,'Blue',3,'Green',
         'B','Variable B',1,'Dog',2,'Cat',3,'Mouse',
         'C','Variable C',1,'Car',2,'House',3,'Tree',
         'D','Variable D',1,'Football',2,'Basketball',3,'Hockey']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


# Convert that second file into something like this
remapDict = {
    'A':{'Variable A':{1:'Red',2:'Blue',3:'Green'}},
    'B':{'Variable B':{1:'Dog',2:'Cat',3:'Mouse'}},
    'C':{'Variable C':{1:'Car',2:'House',3:'Tree'}},
    'D':{'Variable D':{1:'Football',2:'Basketball',3:'Hockey'}}}


for col in df1.columns:
    remapData = remapDict[col]
    newColName = f'{col}. {list(remapData.keys())[0]}'
    df1 = df1.rename(columns={col:f'{newColName}'})
    df1[newColName] = df1[newColName].map(remapData[f'{list(remapData.keys())[0]}'])
```

**Before:**

```
print(df1)
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  2  3
1  2  2  1  2
2  3  1  3  3
```

**After:**

```
print(df1)
  A. Variable A B. Variable B C. Variable C D. Variable D
0           Red           Dog         House        Hockey
1          Blue           Cat           Car    Basketball
2         Green           Dog          Tree        Hockey
```